# How is this json format saved in my database called?

Tags: mysql, json, format, save

there is a format that I do not know what it is called, but in my database whenever a json is saved to the database it is done in this format.

How can I convert this format back to Json? Is there an online tool that can do it quickly?

```
a:3:{s:7:"enabled";s:3:"yes";s:12:"notify_email";s:12:"{site_admin}";s:11:"notify_days";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Mon";}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not JSON, but PHP [`serialized`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize) data. You can convert it back to an associative array using [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and then into JSON if required using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode):

```php
$s = 'a:3:{s:7:"enabled";s:3:"yes";s:12:"notify_email";s:12:"{site_admin}";s:11:"notify_days";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Mon";}}';

$arr = unserialize($s);
print_r($arr);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [enabled] => yes
    [notify_email] => {site_admin}
    [notify_days] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mon
        )

)
{
    "enabled": "yes",
    "notify_email": "{site_admin}",
    "notify_days": [
        "Mon"
    ]
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SNBV1)